# The application stop responding when I try to save a 3D map to my local folder

Tags: qgis

I have used QGIS on both AMD and Intel computers and run both versions 3.28 and 3.32 but when I try to save a 3D map the programme crashes. What can be the problem? What should I try?

Comment: perhaps your GPU is not enough to handle it. Are you using an integrated GPU?